# Is Gradle system property in gradle.properies not being used? (javacpp, intellij)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javacv, javacpp

According to the JavaCPP documentation, if we set the system property: `javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64` it should not download the other platforms:

This is from [javacpp](http://bytedeco.org/download/):

> ... This downloads binaries for all platforms, but to get binaries for
>   only one platform we can set the javacpp.platform system property (via
>   the -D command line option) to something like android-arm,
>   linux-x86_64, macosx-x86_64, windows-x86_64, etc.

The way to set system properties in [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> Using the -D command-line option, you can pass a system property to
>   the JVM which runs Gradle. The -D option of the gradle command has the
>   same effect as the -D option of the java command.
>
> You can also set system properties in gradle.properties files with the
>   prefix systemProp.

However it downloads all platforms. I have tried different ways to set that property without any difference:

in gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64    
systemProp.gradle.javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64
systemProp.system.javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64
sysProp.javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64
gradlePropertiesProp.javacpp.platform=linux-x86_64
```

or in build.gradle: (under dependencies)

```
System.setProperty("javacpp.platform","linux-x86_64")
```

In build.gradle I have:

```
compile "org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.4.2"
```

How it is supposed to work?

Comment: To be honest, I never heard that some third-party system properties interfere in any way with Gradle resolving dependencies. Checking out this [issue](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/216) and the [linked example](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/wiki/Configuring-Proguard-for-JavaCV#gradle-settings), I'm pretty sure the system property only works for Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle doesn't support Maven profiles, which we need to get this working. We would need to create a plugin such as 
[sbt-javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/sbt-javacpp) to implement similar functionality with Gradle.