# ProGuard with JavaCPP - Loader warnings

Tags: proguard, javacpp

I've built a fat jar of the [tesseract](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tesseract) [basic example](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/tesseract/samples/BasicExample.java) of 7.9 MB (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819636/build-jar-with-binaries-for-required-platform-only-javacpp)). Now I want to shrink its size using ProGuard. Using [this standard gradle task](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/ProGuard/blob/master/examples/gradle/applications.gradle) with the addition of `keep 'class org.bytedeco.javacpp.** {*;}'` and `dontwarn 'org.bytedeco.javacpp.**'` works just fine (7.6 MB jar size) but I get a lot of warnings when running the jar:

```
Warning: Loader.putMemberOffset(): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.tesseract. ...  
Warning: Loader.putMemberOffset(): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.leptonica. ...
```

(following [this guide](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/wiki/Configuring-Proguard-for-JavaCV) leads to the same result).
I can prevent these warnings by keeping `tesseract` and `leptonica` too:

```
keep 'class org.bytedeco.tesseract.** {*;}'
keep 'class org.bytedeco.leptonica.** {*;}'
```

which results in a minimally larger jar (7.7 MB), but as the program seems to work OK with the warnings I was wondering if there's another way, e.g. by keeping not everything from `org.bytedeco`.

It's a really petty issue, but maybe there's an easy solution for it (the additional 0.1 MB is not a problem at all, just trying to get a little better understanding of javacpp, which is a really great library).

Comment: ProGuard doesn't support anything that uses JNI very well, so that's why we need to do a little bit of manual configurations in those cases. If you don't need the functionality that is getting removed though, there is no need to worry about those warnings.